# getting 404 not found - website with apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

**Background:**

I've installed apache2 and have tried set up virtual directories... but when I try to test the different sites, I keep getting 404 error messages.

The article /tutorial I've been following is located at:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

I have the following folder structure in place:

```
/var/www/webtest.com/test.html
/var/www/ttimes.com/test.php
```

In the /etc/apache2/sites-available folder, I have the following configuration files:

```
jmj@cp-AOA150:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls -lah /var/www/
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4.0K Jul 28 21:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4.0K Jul 28 19:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K May 11  2013 current
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr  3 08:21 html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  177 Nov 23  2013 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  124 Jul 28 20:14 test.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 jmj root 4.0K Jun  6 11:58 ttimes.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 jmj root 4.0K Jul 28 21:21 webtest.com
```

Here's what the webtest.com.conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@webtest.com
        ServerName webtest.com
        ServerAlias www.webtest.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webtest.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's what my hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       cp-AOA150
```

This is all just on a local dev box where I want to have multiple sites located under /var/www.  Once the site is developed, I'm going to move them to my hosting company. 
I currently don't have other IP addresses to add, so I skipped the step of adding VPS server IPs.

I am able to successfully run the

> sudo a2ensite webtest.com.conf

command and I restart apache.

But when I go to my site by typing `http://localhost/webtest.com/test.html`, I get a 404 not found error.

What I've tried so far:
- I've reviewed the article to make sure I didn't miss any steps. 
- proved that apache itself is working by going to `http://localhost.`  When I do that, I get a page that reads:

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Then I stop the apache service and try the same URL.  It fails.

Comment: Did you check folder permissions?

Comment: Bob, I followed the directions at the top of the article for permissions.  The results of the "ls -lah" command in my post shows the resultsl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it setup as a virtual host pointing to webtest.com but you're trying to access it through localhost/. With a VirtualHost it doesn't exist in that path.

The easiest way is to edit your /etc/hosts file to make a local DNS entry for webtest.com. Add a line to that file like this:

```
127.0.0.1     webtest.com
```

Then point your browser to webtest.com and you should see your site.

Comment: bingo! I will accept this as the answer as soon as the site lets me!

Answer (score 7):

You might have to edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You may need to also do `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable module rewrite.”